# How to set height of Tree node?

Tags: extjs, gxt

I am trying to increase the height of tree node. For this i edit default gxt CSS class as bellow.

```
.x-tree3-el {
   height:25px;
}
```

It works fine but when tree has lots of node, it shows white blank space on scrolling.

The issue is in `TreepanelView.class` where there is a in built method as bellow.

```
protected int getCalculatedRowHeight() {
   return 21;
  }
```

Due to this static value I facing this issue. So is there any easy way to increase the height of node?

I am using GXT 2.2.4 library.

Comment: How about overriding getCalculatedRowHeight() for your Treepanel?

Comment: @DmitryPashkevich Yes it will work but I want some easy way.